# SDL on save component check the values in c#

Tags: 2011, core-service, sdl-tridion, c#

Hello Friends I am trying to check or print the component values after the saving event is triggered.

I want to check on each component save. User added the [www.blahblh.com](http://www.blahblh.com) URL or not then take action as per URL I am getting.

```
    public void ComponentSaveAction(Component subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
            {
                   Component comp = subject;
                    
                    string str = comp.Content.Value; // in str values getting empty
            }
```

updated code.

```
    public void ComponentSaveAction(Component subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
        foreach (var items in fields)
        {
            if(items.ToString().Contains("www.blahblah.com"))
            {
                //throw pop up exception 
            }
            else{
                //save logic
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this code I am able to check whether the component field contains the URL or not. Bur problem is its works only for the text fields. How to read the data if the component field contains EmbeddedSchemaField, ComponentLinkField.

Any solution to catch this all filed in parent node level and read as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a few blog posts about this back in the day, you have a few options. Check this article series:

- [Validating Content on Save: part 1](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html)
- [Validating Content on Save: part 2](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913)

I can't seem to find part 3 at the moment.

These articles should point you in the right direction. They show an approach with XML schema validation constraints (not user friendly), an approach with Event System (as you are trying) that allows for a message popup with some details as to why the field is not valid, and - the most user friendly, but more complex solution - using a UI extension.

Comment: Thank you for valuable reply. my scenario is i have multiple components which having multiple fields so my question is when user try to save any component. i want to check  each filed contain the URL e.g www.blahblah.com then show a popup message for url

Comment: Is it possible to get component all filed and its values ? i want to check each component filed and its values while saving.

Comment: @ketanpatil - yes It's possible, Nuno example "Validating Content on Save: part 1" - already has the sample code ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema); you need to play around based on your schema requirements.

Comment: @Velmurugan  and Nuno I have updated my code please check

Comment: All those field classes (except EmbeddedSchemaField, which is a schema) have a .Value property. Check that and play with it.

Comment: You could also look at Component.InnerXml (or something along those lines), if all you want is to scan all content for a string.